# Increase font size of the data in the view pane

Tags: r, rstudio

In `R-Studio` (built `2022.07.1`   `554`), is there a way to `increase` the `font size` of the `data` when a `dataframe` is open in the view pane?

Current view:

[image]

Comment: I use [CTRL]-[+] to increase the size of the entire application

Comment: This is not working in my case, do I need to place the cursor somewhere specific?

Comment: Actually RStudio just as the active window. If you're not using the num pad, try additionally SHIFT. Or if you're in a web browser try CTRL and mouse wheel.

Comment: @jay.sf, this works, but it would be better to individually change the font of `view pane` and etc. Because sometimes you don't want to change the code's font size.

Comment: I feel the same way. I use the Zoom In feature to make everything bigger, then Tools->GlobalOptions->Appearance->EditorFontSize to make the code's font smaller.